# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined but I can actually see the data in the console

Tags: reactjs, redux

basically, I have this component that makes a call to an IMDB-related API and send the result back, I can see the result in the console but I can NOT map over it for some reason!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { searchMovieIMDB } from '../../../actions'

class MovieFormReview extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.searchMovieIMDB(this.props.formValues.title);
    }
    fetchMovieResults() {
        if(this.props.assets.fetchResultsError) {
            return (
                <div className="loading">
                    <h1>{this.props.assets.fetchResultsError}</h1>
                </div>
            );
        } else if(this.props.assets.loadingResults) {
            return (
                <div className="loading">
                    <h1>Loading...</h1>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return this.props.assets.SearchResult.Search.map(series => (
                    <div className="latest" key={series._id}>
                        <h1>{series.title}</h1>
                    </div>
                )
            )
        }
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.assets.SearchResult.Search);
        return (
            <div className="add-new-asset">
                <h2>Please confirm your movie.</h2>
                {this.fetchMovieResults()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ form, assets }) => {
    return {
        formValues: form.movieForm.values,
        assets
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchMovieIMDB })(withRouter(MovieFormReview));
```

[screenshot to the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXVV5.png)

[My Reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGpAW.png)

[My Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dayhO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write fetch methods with multiple possible statuses like this, works in every situation w/o errors.

General idea behind this: you check all possible statuses but if none match, return loading state.

```js
fetchMovieResults() {
  const {assets} = this.props;      

  if (assets) {
    if (assets.fetchResultsError) {
      // if error
      return (
        <div className="loading">
          <h1>{assets.fetchResultsError}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (assets.SearchResult && assets.SearchResult.Search && assets.SearchResult.Search.length > 0) {
      // if data and more than 0
      return assets.SearchResult.Search.map(series => (
        <div className="latest" key={series._id}>
          <h1>{series.title}</h1>
        </div>
      ));
    }
  }

  // no error or data
  // has to be loading
  return (
    <div className="loading">
       <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

#### Edit

Why my code works but yours doesn't?

(This is speculation because I don't know all your code)

`componentDidMount` fires after component is mounted and rendered the first time which means that your *fetch API* code is fired after component is already rendered first time (which is good practice).

This means that your action is fired and reducer adds `loadingResults` state **AFTER** the first render which means that:

```js
if (this.props.assets.fetchResultsError) {
  // this check fails
} else if (this.props.assets.loadingResults) {
  // this check fails
} else {
  // this code runs but you don't have
  // data yet and you'll get an error
}
```

My answer works in every situation because "loading" state is default option.

Comment: hmmm when I saw your code it seemed the same for me but it actually worked! you mind explain to me the difference? especially that I use this way all the time and its the very first time it throws such an error for me.

Comment: that actually makes more sense! thanks @solo! that really helped! :)

Comment: @Laylaz No problem. Keep in mind that Im not super familiar with Redux, "problem" could also be in `searchMovieIMDB` (which I don't know much about) but my method still works in every situation.

Comment: I actually have a screenshot of it in the question you can check it if you want!

Comment: @Laylaz Yes, I saw all the images, Im just not familiar with `connect` and `dispatch` internals and don't know if the cause is the there. But if you already use Redux, I'd recommend to learn it even more from docs or YouTube. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that your problem is that when you call the map the result is null, but  when you log to the console the values already filled. you should check if the value is filled async, and if it does you should call the map only when the values filled.

Comment: my initial state is [] and It stays loading until my state is ready you can check it in the screenshot I just added.:)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `render` will be called before `componentDidMount`, so your Redux store will be empty on first render. In your `fetchMovieResults` your default behaviour is to iterate through `this.props.assets.SearchResult.Search`, which will be `undefined` until the asynchronous call finishes. Both `this.props.assets.fetchResultsError` and `this.props.assets.loadingResults` will be `undefined` as well, ending on the `else` that causes the error.

Simple solution, check for that on your `else` :

```
fetchMovieResults() {
    if(this.props.assets.fetchResultsError) {
        return (
            <div className="loading">
                <h1>{this.props.assets.fetchResultsError}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    } else if(this.props.assets.loadingResults) {
        return (
            <div className="loading">
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
            </div>
        );
    } else if( typeof this.props.assets.Search !== 'undefined' &&
               typeof this.props.assets.SearchResult.Search !== 'undefined') {
        return this.props.assets.SearchResult.Search.map(series => (
                <div className="latest" key={series._id}>
                    <h1>{series.title}</h1>
                </div>
            )
        )
    }

    return null
}
```

Comment: This would actually be right except that I set all this up in the reducer you can check it in the screenshot now.:)

Comment: @laylaz In the screenshot you only show the result of the reducers, but that still would only reflect after the action is resolved. Do your default state cover that too?  Can't see that on the screenshots.

Comment: I got it sorry, I didn't actually get what u meant the first time, my bad:D